Sign a pdf on all pages with a single revision (signature on all pages instead of signature on one page and appearance on others) using 2 step signing
To sign a pdf on all pages with a single revision (signature on all pages instead of signature on one page and appearance on others) with a two step signing process.
Server will create a PDF with signature fields and send the base64 hash of the document to use for signing. User will connect the USB token to the system and a client will read the token and sign the document and return the signature hash (this is working)
So far, using iText 7 i have been able to create a document with signature with fields on all pages and send it for signing however, when the signature hash is returned i have not had success in actually putting the signature on all pages.
I suspect the issue might be with createSignature method, with this implementation it is throwing error with field not exists (however i can see the fields with the signature util class using the same document)
@Test
    public void testMultipleAppearancesMkI() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String src = "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/portrait-note.pdf"; // Source PDF
        String dest = "/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/one-sign-temp.pdf"; // Destination PDF

        try (
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(src);
                ByteArrayOutputStream preparedArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        ) {
            String signerName = "Abhinav Kumar ";
            PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, preparedArrayStream, new StampingProperties()) {
                @Override
                protected PdfSigFieldLock createNewSignatureFormField(PdfAcroForm acroForm, String name)
                        throws IOException {
                    PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock = super.createNewSignatureFormField(acroForm, name);

                    PdfSignatureFormField sigField = (PdfSignatureFormField) acroForm.getField(fieldName);

                    PdfWidgetAnnotation widget = sigField.getWidgets().get(0);
                    widget.getPage().removeAnnotation(widget);
                    sigField.remove(PdfName.AP);
                    sigField.remove(PdfName.Subtype);
                    sigField.remove(PdfName.P);
                    sigField.remove(PdfName.FT);
                    int numberOfPages = document.getNumberOfPages();

                    for(int i=1; i<= numberOfPages ; i ++){
                        PdfPage pdfPage = document.getPage(i);
                        PdfDictionary signatureDictionary = cryptoDictionary.getPdfObject();
                        sigField.addKid(createSubField(pdfPage, 10, 10, 100, 20,
                                signerName, signatureDictionary, document, String.valueOf(i)));
                    }
                    return pdfSigFieldLock;
                }
            };

            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), writer);

            PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(pdfDoc, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.ETSI_CAdES_DETACHED);
            pdfSigner.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);

            byte[] signatureHash = usbTokenSignatureSimulation(external.getHash());
            finalSign(signatureHash, preparedArrayStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    PdfFormField createSubField(PdfPage page, float x, float y, float width, float height, String signerName,
                                PdfDictionary signatureDictionary, PdfDocument pdfDocument, String fieldName) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(180, 600, 150, 50);
        PdfFormXObject form = new PdfFormXObject(rectangle);
        try (   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(form, pdfDocument)) {
            canvas.setFontSize(7);
            canvas.add(new Paragraph().setPadding(0)
                    .setMargin(0).add("Digitally Signed using DSC :"));
            canvas.add(new Paragraph().setPadding(0).setMargin(0).add(signerName));
            canvas.add(new Paragraph().setPadding(0).setMargin(0).add("2024-06-12 23:34:34"));
        }

        PdfDictionary ap = new PdfDictionary();
        ap.put(PdfName.N, form.getPdfObject());

        PdfWidgetAnnotation widget = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
        widget.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT | PdfAnnotation.LOCKED);
        widget.setPage(page);
        widget.put(PdfName.AP, ap);

        PdfSignatureFormField sigField = PdfFormField.createSignature(pdfDocument);
        sigField.setFieldName(fieldName);
        sigField.addKid(widget);
        sigField.put(PdfName.V, signatureDictionary);
        page.addAnnotation(widget);
        return sigField;
    }


    public void finalSign(byte[] encodedSig, ByteArrayOutputStream preparedArrayStream) throws Exception {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream preparedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream((preparedArrayStream.toByteArray()))) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(preparedInputStream);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/", "finalSign.pdf"), false);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(outputStream));
            SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
//            byte[] decodeSignature = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);
            ExternalBlankSignatureContainer blankSignatureContainer = new ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer(encodedSig);
            PdfSigner.signDeferred(pdfDocument, "Signature1.1", outputStream, blankSignatureContainer);
//        PdfSigner.signDeferred(pdfDocument, "Signature1.2", outputStream, blankSignatureContainer);
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] usbTokenSignatureSimulation(byte[] hash) throws KeyStoreException, IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, InvalidKeyException,
            NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException {
        BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(providerBC);

        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/abhinav/Work/dev/client-wca.p12");

        /* Reading the certificate from a tempory store */
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(inStream, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "!234Qwer".toCharArray());
        Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

        // create PCKS7 for getting attributes
        Certificate[] certificates= Arrays.asList(certificate).toArray(new Certificate[0]);

        IExternalDigest externalDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        String digestAlgorithm = "SHA256";

            /*
            Below block added to simulate signature on USB token
             */
        // prepare PdfPKCS7 with document hash
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7((PrivateKey) null, certificates, digestAlgorithm, null, externalDigest, false);
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, null, null);
        // retrieve signature bytes
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initSign(key);
        sig.update(sh);

        byte[] extSignature = sig.sign();
        // finalize PdfPKCS7 with signature bytes
        sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, "RSA");
        byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, null, null, null);
        /* Simulation ends  */
        return encodedSig;
    }

    class PreSignatureContainer implements IExternalSignatureContainer {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private byte hash[];
        PdfDocument pdfDoc;
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance2;
        public PreSignatureContainer( PdfDocument pdfDocument, PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            this.pdfDoc = pdfDocument;
            sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
            String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
            BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

            try {
                this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
            }

            return new byte[0];
        }

        @Override
        public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
            signDic.putAll(sigDic);
        }

        public byte[] getHash() {
            return hash;
        }
    }

    class ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer extends ExternalBlankSignatureContainer
    {
        byte[] cmsSignatureContents;

        public ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer(byte[] cmsSignatureContents) {
            super(new PdfDictionary());
            this.cmsSignatureContents = cmsSignatureContents;
        }

        @Override
        public  byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws CertificateException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            return cmsSignatureContents;
        }
    }

UPDATE : The code snippet has been edited with inputs provided by @mkl. It works as a multi step signing process, generating a hash and sending this to another service reading from USB token and generating the signature hash. The final step is taking the signature bytes/hash and injecting in the prepared document.

The concept of your approach as is cannot work.
In prepareSignature you add a signature field to each page. That's ok. Then you try to prepare all those signatures for signing. That's ok, too, if done correctly. What is not ok, though, is that you attempt to calculate the document hash for each signature here.
When you sign a PDF multiple times, you get something like in this sketch:

(For some details and backgrounds see this answer.)
So the document hash that a later signature signs also covers the earlier signatures. In your case, though, you don't have injected those earlier signatures yet! Thus, you can only use the hash you calculated for the initial signature in your prepareSignature methods, all other hashes will change when you insert the first signature into its placeholder.
Thus, you cannot first prepare all signature fields and calculate their document hashes, then sign all those hashes in one call, and eventually inject all the signatures, you have to at least calculate the next hash to sign after injecting the previous signature.

Other than that there also are errors in your implementation: In the loop at the end of prepareSignature you start each iteration with the document with all fields added but none prepared yet. This would allow you to create multiple copies of your document, each with a different page signed, but not a single document with all pages signed.
Also I don't understand at all your intention in the part after calling prepareSignature in initiateSigning, starting with ignoring the return value of that call which contains the alleged document hashes after all.

thanks for the background information. I have had success adding a single signature and adding appearance on other pages but my requirement is to have a document with signature on all pages under a single revision. (document hash to be sent to a client which will read from USB )
I would be grateful if you can give some guidance on how I can achieve it using itext 7. Moreover it will be a multi step process where in document hash will be sent to client, the client will read the USB token and return a CMS container which needs to be go on all the pages in the pdf document.

"my requirement is to have a document with signature on all pages under a single revision" - To have multiple signature widgets added in the same revision, they must refer to the same actual signature. The PDF specification tries to forbid this, signature fields shall never refer to more than one annotation (ISO 32000-2, section 12.7.5.5). Thus, iText does not explicitly offer this option. In practice, though, hardly any validator complains about signatures with multiple widgets, in particular not Adobe Acrobat. Thus, many people ignore the specification here and create such signatures...

... In 2022 I tested creating multi-widget signatures with iText in a way that does not violate the words of the specification and it did work then, see this test class. Essentially I derived a new class from PdfSigner and overwrote its createNewSignatureFormField method. You are welcome to test whether that code still works.

You're a life saver. Thanks for sharing the test class, i tweaked it to use the Signdeferred (updated above as well) method since the private key won't be available at the time of actual signing.
A multi page page will have n pages  and signDefered expects field name as an input.
Question: calling signDeferred once using the one of the field name will  link to all signature containers created with the PdfSigner Reference ?

I haven't tried that but I would expect that calling signDeferred for any of the newly added fields should work.

I did both the ways and using the Signature panel from adobe acrobat, was able to verify it. Signing it once was successful and all signatures were verified and under a single revision while calling the signDeferred multiple times complained about the format.
Thanks again @mkl.

Great that it works! Yes, signing once for an arbitrary one of the generated fields should work just fine.

@AbhinavKumar But please note as mkl already mentioned (cp. above comment) This will not work anymore starting with PDF 2.0 since the spec forbids it: "signature fields shall never refer to more than one annotation (ISO 32000-2, section 12.7.5.5)"

@Lonzak Strictly speaking the test code I referenced does not violate the spec as it's written: In contrast to many single-signature-many-visualizations implementations each widget here does have its own field. The trick is that all those fields share the same value which is not explicitly forbidden. Of course this still violates the original intention of the quoted part of the spec but at least not its letter... ;)

Interesting differentiation! Still I would concur that this "violates the original intention of the quoted part of the spec". But I'll keep that in mind - who knows maybe I'll need that in future :-)
